# JSF 2.0: How include <h:head> attributes?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

i'm with a problem, if i use:

```
<head>
    .. stylesheet and javascripts 
</head>
```

My style from stylesheet is all right, but with an alert in the bottom:
"One or more resources have the fate of 'head', but no component of 'head' was defined in the view."

so if i change `<head>` by `<h:head>` the warning disappear but my style gone too..

what is the problem ?

**UPDATE**:

```
// index.xhtml
<head>
    <ui:include src="jsf/components/head_index.xhtml" id="head" />
</head>
<h:body styleClass="nojs"> 
...
</h:body>

// head_index.xhtml   
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
                xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="#{request.contextPath}/images/logo.ico" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Script-Type" content="text/javascript" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="robots" content="index, follow" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="title" content="" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />

    <title>TITLE</title>
    <!-- ////////////////////////////////// -->
    <!-- //      Start Stylesheets       // -->
    <!-- ////////////////////////////////// -->
    <link href="./css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="./css/nivo-slider.css" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <!-- ////////////////////////////////// -->
    <!-- //      Javascript Files        // -->
    <!-- ////////////////////////////////// -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/cufon-yui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/geosanslight_500.font.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
             Cufon.replace('h1') ('h2') ('h3') ('h4') ('h5') ('h6') ('.middle-text');

    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.lavalamp.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.easing.1.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
            $(document).ready(function(){
            /* Function for lavalamp navigation menu and dropdown */
            $("#menu").lavaLamp({
                    fx: "backout",
                    speed: 700
            });

            $(" #menu ul ").css({display: "none"}); // Opera Fix
            $(" #menu li").hover(function(){
            $(this).find('ul:first').css({visibility: "visible",display: "none"}).slideDown(400);
            },function(){
            $(this).find('ul:first').css({visibility: "hidden"});
            });

            /* if javascript disabled */
            $("body").removeClass("nojs").addClass("js");




    });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    /* homepage slideshow */
    $(window).load(function() {
            $('#slider').nivoSlider({
                    effect:'random', //Specify sets like: 'fold,fade,sliceDown'
                    slices:15,
                    animSpeed:500, //Slide transition speed
                    pauseTime:6000,
                    directionNav:false, //Next &amp; Prev
                    startSlide:0 //Set starting Slide (0 index)
            });
    });
    </script>
    <!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://demo.templatesquare.com/html/genesis/genesis-default/js/DD_roundies_0.0.2a-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://demo.templatesquare.com/html/genesis/genesis-default/js/ie_rounded_config.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</ui:composition>


//top 
<div id="top">
    <div id="topleft">
        <div id="logo">
            <h1><a href="./index.xhtml">PROJECT</a></h1>
        </div><!-- end #logo -->
    </div><!-- end #topleft -->
```

**UPDATE 2:**
i'm trying the @Vineet and @George suggestion, but i'm with a trouble:
This works :

```
<link href="#{request.contextPath}/css/style.css" rel="styleSheet" type="text/css"/>
```

But when i try to use in JSF like:

```
<h:outputStylesheet name="./css/style.css" />
```

The structure of the folder is:

```
WebPages
   META-INF
   WEB-INF
   css
   html
   images
   js
   jsf
   ..// .xhtml files
```

It doesn't work...

Any idea guys ?

Best regards,
Valter Henrique.

Comment: Statements like `but with an alert in the bottom` are very obtuse. Where does this error appear? Does it appear in the browser, or in the server logs or elsewhere? Also, would I be right in assuming that the statement `the warning disappear but my style gone too`, would be interpreted as `the warning has disappeared but my style is not present in the HTML document`?

Comment: @Vineet, the error appears in the bottom of the html page, in the browser.
i think the warning is generated automatically by the jsf compiler, my guess.

Comment: Are you running the application in the Development mode? If not, I would suggest doing so, so that you can take a look at the component tree in the event of an error.

Comment: Also, do take a look at the facelet tag library docs for [`h:outputScript`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/h/outputScript.html) and [`h:outputStyleSheet`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/h/outputStylesheet.html). I suspect you haven't used them correctly. Posting your code would help in understanding the problem better.

Comment: @Vinnet, i update my post, i'm showing how i'm including the stylesheet and the javascript.

Comment: @Valter Henrique Does your code works now?

Comment: @Valter, what is the problem you are facing? I do not see any problems in your code; this on Mojarra and not RichFaces though.

Comment: @Vineet, my problem is in the 'top' div, the text 'PROJECT' is not stylized, i don't know what do.
Especially that everything else works fine..

Comment: This looks more like a HTML/CSS issue more than a JSF issue. I noticed that the `link` tags were added in the document, so you'll need to verify what styles have been applied to the `h1` tag. Use Firebug or a similar tool for debugging whether the stylesheet contains the required rule.

Comment: @Vineet, i update my post again, please take a look now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `#{request.contextPath}` to point absolute app location.
If your scripts located in `js` folder of your app, you can use

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="#{request.contextPath}/js/jquery.lavalamp.js"/>
```

or `h:outputScript` and `h:outputStyleSheet` as @Vineet Reynolds suggested

**UPDATE:** 
if you want to use `h:outputStyleSheet` you should create `resources` folder in `WebPages` and copy `css` and `js` folder in it. So the structure of the folder will be

```
WebPages
   META-INF
   WEB-INF
   resources
      css
      js
   html
   images
   jsf
   ..// .xhtml files
```

then you can use `h:outputStyleSheet` such way :

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="style.css" />
```

and for javascript

```
<h:outputScript library="js" name="somejs.js"/>
```

For more details about packaging resources in jsf 2 look at [this post](http://blogs.oracle.com/rlubke/entry/jsf_2_0_new_feature5)